# can't serialize class mongodb spark

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, apache-spark

In my application, there is a model class as

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class Observation implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
}
```

I serialized this class by implementing Serializable interface. This class is model of MongoDB collection. Everything is okey for mapping MongoDB record to Observation object.

When I run my app, Spark jobs do map-reduce jobs. After map reduce, I get this exception. I added stack trace:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task ID 133
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class    com.mongodb.spark.demo.Observation
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:284)
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:185)
at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:131)
at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:33)
at com.mongodb.BSONBinaryWriter.encodeDocument(BSONBinaryWriter.java:339)
at com.mongodb.InsertCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(InsertCommandMessage.java:45)
at com.mongodb.InsertCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(InsertCommandMessage.java:23)
at com.mongodb.BaseWriteCommandMessage.encodeMessageBody(BaseWriteCommandMessage.java:69)
at com.mongodb.BaseWriteCommandMessage.encodeMessageBody(BaseWriteCommandMessage.java:23)
at com.mongodb.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:66)
at com.mongodb.BaseWriteCommandMessage.encode(BaseWriteCommandMessage.java:53)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.sendWriteCommandMessage(DBCollectionImpl.java:473)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.writeWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:427)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:387)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:186)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:165)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:161)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:107)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:966)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:934)
at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.write(MongoRecordWriter.java:93)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.org$apache$spark$rdd$PairRDDFunctions$$writeShard$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:716)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So, why I'm getting this exception? Can anyone help me to find solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I extend my class via BasicDBObject, problem is resolved.

So, latest and correct version of class is given below

```
public class Observation extends BasicDBObject implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the problem is because you don't have a default constructor

```
public Observation () {
}
```

Comment: my problem is about serialization. When I extend Observation class via BasicDBObject class, problem is resolved. Thanks.